# Nvidia external monitors are laggy

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, screen

I am using the version **22.04 of Ubuntu** and I recently installed the recommended drivers **nvidia-525-propietary**.

All seems to work well on my laptop.

Running nvidia-smi detects my card correctly.

The problem occurs when I have external monitors. These are laggy to the point of being unusable.

I am using a **GTX 1660 Ti Mobile**.

How do I get external monitors working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try first:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

and then restart:

```
reboot
```

This is not an ideal solution because after that you will have the integrated card turned off

Comment: This will turn the discrete card ON.

Comment: Pilot6, you are absolutely right

Answer (score 1):

I have a 32gb RAM + Nvidia/Intel laptop (GS76 Stealth) and my 4k external display was super laggy (only this display ON). I use 150% fractional scale for readability.

I do have `prime-select` and have `nvidia`, and even disabled the Intel one in the BIOS.

This lag issue wasn't happening before, and the laptop monitor works very fluent.

Until I noticed that when my external monitor worked correctly, I was using X11 instead of Wayland...

So yes, that was the issue. Before logging in, you must select Ubuntu on XOrg.

[image]